# Checkboxes in Rails - Value chosen not displaying in 'Show', undefined method `merge' for "a":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, capybara

I'm having a set of problems that are doing my head in! Kind of a Rails newb so I'm having trouble figuring this out.

I've got a field for my 'Question' model that's called 'Answers_expected', which I want to have two options for, 'One' or 'Multiple', rather than just a normal text input.

My Questions_controller.rb (relevant lines):

```
before_action :set_answers_expected 
  private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_question
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:title, :brief, :idea_id, :user_id, :answers_expected)
end

def set_answers_expected
  @answers_expected = [
    "One",
    "Multiple"
  ]
end
```

Questions.rb (relevant line):

`validates :answers_expected, presence: true`

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <% if @question.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@question.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this question from  being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @question.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :title, "Question" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :title, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :brief, "Description" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :brief, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :answers_expected %><br>
        <% @answers_expected.each do |a| %>
          <%= f.label :a, class: 'checkbox' do %>
            <%= f.check_box :answers_expected, "a" %>
            <%= a %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
  </div>
```

My Questions show.html.erb:

```
div class="question">
  <p>
    <strong>Question:</strong>
    <%= @question.title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Brief:</strong>
    <%= @question.brief %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Answers expected:</strong>
    <%= @question.answers_expected %>
  </p>
```

For some reason on my server, I get an error `undefined method`merge' for "a":String`pointing to line`<%= f.check_box :answers_expected, "a" %>`in _form.html.erb, but it works when I change`f.check_box`to`f.radio_button`; why?

Even with radio_button, however, the `Answers Expected` display on the server continuously shows zero, despite what I click, which I also don't understand.

Also wrote specs hoping to point me in the right direction here:

`question_spec.rb`:

```
scenario 'with valid params' do
  click_link 'Create a question'
  fill_in 'Question', with: 'Valid question'
  fill_in 'Description', with: 'This is valid description for the question.'
  check 'One'
  click_button 'Create Question'
  page.should have_content 'One'
  expect(page).to have_content('Question was successfully created.')
end
```

With my `session_helper.rb` having:

```
def submit_question(title = 'valid title', brief = 'valid brief')
  click_link 'Create a question'
  fill_in 'Question', with: title
  fill_in 'Description', with: brief
  check 'One'
  click_button 'Create Question'
end
```

And my failed spec:

```
1) Visitor submits a question with valid params
 Failure/Error: page.should have_content 'One'
   expected to find text "One" in "Toggle navigation Labthi.ng Home Explore Recent    Activity Example User Sign out × Question was successfully created. 0 Title: Valid Title Phase: 1 Brief: Valid brief for an idea Image: Active: true Components: App Categories: Other User: Example User Direct Define Reputation Activity Question was successfully created. Question: Valid question Brief: This is valid description for the question. Answers expected: 0 Idea: Valid brief for an idea User: Example User No comments. Add comment No answers yet. Why don't you add one ? Add answer Edit | Back"
 # ./spec/features/question_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Very confused! This is messing with my understanding of Rails a bit.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Changed the syntax to `<%= f.check_box :answers_expected, value: "a" %>` , but the answers expected on the show page is still displaying as zero?

Comment: Use this syntax: `f.check_box :answers_expected, value: "a"`

Comment: Thanks. But it still displays on the show page, answers expected = 0?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set a value with the the `check_box` form helper is:

`<%= f.check_box :answers, {}, "a" %>` 
`:answers` is the field name 
`{}` is where you would put html attributes like class or id 
`"a"` will be the value :)